# Google v3 API and Oauth - Do I need to use the json file?

Tags: oauth, google-api, youtube-api, google-php-sdk

In the official docs for the Google API and OAuth, it has you download a .json file that includes things like clientid, secret, redirect etc.  Then it has you build your Google Client like this (I'm using PHP and offline access to interface with the Youtube API):

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
```

However, I've seen examples that allow you to define this information within PHP and set them on the object individually, instead of via the setAuthConfig .json file inclusion.  In my case, that's what I want to do so I can have better control over my redirect url and allow storage of my clientid and secret within my settings forms/database.  The examples I've seen look like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientid);
$client->setClientSecret($secret);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
```

Are both of these methods valid ways to define the Oauth Google Client in the current (v3) Google API and Oauth?

Comment: AFAIK, the first one is the support flow in the documents. But  you could also try the second code. In the [Creating a Google API Console project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) and [CodePen sample](http://codepen.io/gtex/pen/MwJggg.html), it follows the second code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think either is specific to a single google service (ie. docs vs youtube, etc) if that's what you're saying.  I think "oauth is oauth", so the same approach works across the api for authentication...although maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah you are correct, what I am saying is that the first authentication code that you've provided is currently used in most API quickstart (I'm also using this).  I've haven't tried using the second auth code you've provided. I'll try it and check its behavior.

Comment: Thanks.  It currently seems to work, but I"m having other issues that (I think) are unrelated.  So this post is simply a clarification that this won't cause any unintended problems by building the Google object this way.